# Scanf not accepting second char string

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have a binary search function that will search for a word in an array, but before I can search the array I need to know what word to search for.  I have written the code to ask the user for input, but the program prints out the request for input but doesn't accept anything from the user.  I was thinking it was a buffer issue, as I have an initial scanf in the program that loads all the character strings from an external file and places them in an array.  I have tried using fflush after my initial scanf, and I tried rewriting the second one with gets, as pointed out in previous threads.  Perhaps I am not implementing it correctly.  Here's what I have so far, any tips as to why the second scanf isn't working is appreciated.

```
#include "set.h"
#include "sortAndSearch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
char names[320][30];
char str[30];  
int i, j;
char *key;
int numOfWords;
char userWord[30];
Set set1, set2, set3;

//scan each char string into array names
for(i=0; scanf("%s", str) != EOF; i++){
        strcpy(names[i], str);
}

//set number of words in file
numOfWords = i;

//sort names array
//bubbleSort(names, numOfWords);

//print out names, sorted
//for(i=0; i<numOfWords; i++){
//      printf("%s\n", names[i]);
//}

printf("What word would you like to search for? ");
scanf("%s", userWord);

//addName2Set(set1, userWord);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to read a *line* of input, use a function that reads a line. Otherwise, you are reading the word and leaving the line ending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial `scanf()` in a loop read everything up to EOF, so there's nothing left for the 'What word would you like to search for?' `scanf()` to read.

One way around this problem is to read the initial names from a file (`fopen()`, `fscanf()`, `fclose()` — and the file name might be an argument to the program, or a fixed name).

Another way you could try is `clearerr(stdin);` before the 'What word' `scanf()`.  That (`clearerr()`) unsets the EOF bit and allows `scanf()` to try again.  It may work if the input of the program is the terminal; it won't help if the input of the program is coming from a file.

---

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char names[320][30];
    char str[30];  
    int i, j;
    char *key;
    int numOfWords;
    char userWord[30];
    Set set1, set2, set3;
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s word-file\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s word-file\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    //scan each char string into array names
    for (i = 0; i < 320 && fscanf(fp, "%29s", str) != EOF; i++)
    {
        strcpy(names[i], str);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    //set number of words in file
    numOfWords = i;
```

This insists that you use `./a.out example.dat` (instead of `./a.out < example.dat`).  It will then work more or less as you want it to.  Of course, the code for reading the file should be in a function that is passed the file name, the array, and the array size.  The 320 in the loop is overflow protection and should be an enumeration `enum { MAX_WORDS = 320 };` that's used both in the array declaration and the loop.  The `29` is overflow protection; it is hard to parameterize that, but it is one less than the second dimension of the array.

Comment: why wouldn't that scanf terminate at the end of the data.dat file?

Comment: the file name is not fixed, it is supplied when the program is run, ./a.out < example.dat

Comment: `clearerr(stdin);` didn't do the trick either.  The initial input comes from an external file, second input comes from within terminal.

Comment: If you're redirecting input from a file like that, then neither `clearerr()` nor anything else is going to help. Which platform are you on? On Unix, you could consider opening and reading `/dev/tty`, or even (daft as it sounds) reading from `stdout` or `stderr`.  But while `stdin` is redirected from a file, the 'What word' `scanf()` is doomed to failure; you've read the whole file and there's nothing let for it to read. (You could rewind `stdin` and choose a word at random, but that would not allow you to search for words not in the list.) I recommend providing the word list as an argument.

Comment: Note that when your first loop executes, it is reading from the file you redirected; the program does not read from the terminal when you invoke it as `./a.out < example.dat`.  The 'What word' `scanf()` is also reading from the same place.  `stdin` does not get magically switched simply because the input was all read into the program.

Comment: Okay, so can I switch `stdin` so that it reads from 'What word'?  Wouldn't the `scanf()` still use the same `stdin` stream?  We havent gotten that far in class, but I don't see how I can test my binary search for a string if I can't accept the string to search for.  I don't understand how I can use `fopen()` without knowing what the file imported is to be called.

Comment: That worked!  I'm thrilled to have it working, but part of the assignment stipulates that the grader will run the program with a command like a.out < ourDataFile

Comment: OK - so where do the words to search for come from?  And which platform are you on?  Are you sure there isn't a count of the number of words to read in the first line of the file, or something like that?  If there was a count, then you'd do a counting loop to read the list of words, and a non-counting loop to read extra words.  That tends to be the way I've seen problems written, but I don't know your course.  Without the exact verbiage, it is impossible for us to know what the requirements are.

Comment: The total number of words is not to exceed 320, but could be anywhere between 0-320.  If I understand you correctly, I could set up the first loop to go for 320 strings instead of EOF and then the second scanf will be able to do its thing.

Comment: I don't know...I haven't got the rubric of your assignment.

Comment: I'm thinking you probably dont want this, but heres the assignment sheet just in case.  I've moved on to just hard coding the words to search for.  All that needs to work are my functions, the rest of my program gets replaced by the grader anyway.  thanks for all your help.  [assignment](http://pastebin.com/HdTrKwu1)

Comment: I've read the assignment; I'd have lots of questions for the instructor.  I can see how to read the data.  Sorting the data is fine.  I can see how to write the recursive binary sort (that's been asked about here, too).  What I don't see is why you'd need the sets (unless there can be repetitions in the input data), or how you're supposed to exercise the binary search, or the indexed lookup. Maybe assignment Major 1 covers that; I have my doubts.  So, I'd be in contact with the instructor about this. The data is guaranteed 'tame' (not more than 320 entries; no entry longer than 29 characters).

Answer (score 4):

Your second `scanf` doesn't work because your first `scanf` never terminates.  `scanf` won't return `EOF` unless the input stream is closed - that would be that the console closes.

Since `scanf` returns the number of characters read you should instead make your loop condition `scanf(%s, str) != 0`.  That will make the loop end as soon as the user hits enter without entering anything.

Comment: I changed `for(i=0; scanf("%s", str) != 0; i++)` but now I get a segmentation fault

Comment: the EOF is there because it is taking input from an external file and I don't know how much data is in that file.  User is not prompted until second scanf.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the first `scanf()` never executes'?  If the input is redirected from a file (there's a comment to the effect that's what happens), then the loop will execute `scanf()` repeatedly until the end of file.  If the input is from a terminal, typing control-Z on Windows or control-D (typically) on Unix will terminate the input.  In all cases, `scanf()` in the loop executes happily.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - meant never terminates not never excecutes

Comment: @manalishi - if you're redirect a file to stdin then once the file is read stdin is at the EOF of the file.  It doesn't get redirected back to the console.  Use `fopepn`, `fscanf`, and `fclose` to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your question and code seemed awfully misaligned at first glance...

`scanf()` is the wrong function for reading from your file, you want `fscanf()`, or if the file is formatted such that each word is on its own line `fgets()` works too (newline stops reading of each string).  Likewise, you can use `gets()` instead of `scanf()` to read user input if the input is just a string followed by return(newline).

[Everything you need to know about stdio.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/)